# Accessing XPages Data Source in a Plugin

Tags: xpages

For a plugin (like the extension library) I try to access the datasource with a given "var" name. Accessing the Datasource object is very easy with the following code:

m_DataSourceName contains the name (var) of the datasource.

```
public DataSource getDataSource() {
    if (StringUtil.isNotEmpty(m_DataSourceName)) {

        UIViewRoot vrCurrent = getFacesContext().getViewRoot();
        if (vrCurrent instanceof UIViewRootEx) {
            for (DataSource dsCurrent : ((UIViewRootEx) vrCurrent)
                    .getData()) {
                if (m_DataSourceName.equals(dsCurrent.getVar())) {
                    return dsCurrent;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Datasource name:" + m_DataSourceName);
    return null;
}
```

I'm getting the datasource back and I can cast this datasource:

```
private TabularDataModel getTDM(DataSource dsCurrent, FacesContext context) {
        try {
            if (dsCurrent instanceof ModelDataSource) {
                ModelDataSource mds = (ModelDataSource) dsCurrent;
                AbstractDataSource ads = (AbstractDataSource) mds;
                ads.load(context);
                System.out.println(ads.getBeanId());
                if (ads.getBeanId() == null) {

                }
                DataModel tdm = mds.getDataModel();
                if (tdm instanceof TabularDataModel) {
                    TabularDataModel tds = (TabularDataModel) tdm;
                    return tds;
                }
            }
            return null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

And now I wanna access the TDM.getRowCount() and this point I'm getting a nullpointer exception. The datasource contains a notes view. Did I miss anything to initialize the datasource?

Comment: If you are using a notes view you will receive an instance of *DominoViewDataModel*. This requires a instance of a *com.ibm.xsp.component.FacesDataIterator* to access the *getRows* method. If this is set, the nullpointer exception goes away...

Comment: Thanks Sven, I will try this. Should I use a subclass of com.ibm.xsp.component.FacesDataIterator or building a own implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution for your problem:

This will give you all **lines** of a view, **not the entry count***. F.e. if you have a categorized view with 5 categories and 1 entry for each category, this will result in 10 lines. The entry count is 5.

First, create a dummy class which implements *FacesDataIterator*

```
public class DummyDataIterator implements com.ibm.xsp.component.FacesDataIterator{

    public DataModel getDataModel() {
        return null;
    }

    public int getFirst() {
        return 0;
    }

    public int getRowIndex() {
        return 0;
    }

    public int getRows() {
        return 0;
    }

    public void setFirst(int paramInt) {}

    public void setRows(int paramInt) {}
}
```

And then you have to do the following:

1. Set the data iterator

   ```
   tdm.setDataControl( new DummyDataIterator() );
   ```
2. Init the row counter for the first time

   ```
   tdm.getRowCount();
   ```
3. Calculate the exact row count with a navigator

   ```
   (( com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.viewnavigator.NOIViewNavigatorEx) tdm.getDominoViewDataContainer().getNavigator()).calculateExactCount(tdm.getView());
   ```

Now your row count is initialized, you can get the result with a normal *getRowCount*:

```
System.out.println("Rows: " +  tdm.getRowCount() );
```

Hope this helps!

**:*

```
tdm.getView().getAllEntries().getCount()
```

Comment: I tried out, and it works fine, till I try to access rowdatas. So I changed the tdm.setDataControl( new DummyDataIterator ) to tmd.setDataControl( new UIDataEX() ) and all works fine and without the 3. Calclulate the exact row part .... Thanks Sven for your support. You will find the full solution in the new POI 4 XPages Project on OpenNTF